# inherited modules should not be compile without any changes in gwt

Tags: maven, gwt, module

I am working on GWT project which having 10 modules like module-1, module-2 ...module-10.
    we have inherited all modules in **application.gwt.xml** which is kept in main module. Main module is entry point and remaining modules are added as **jar**.

```
    <inherits name="com.company.Core" />
    <inherits name="com.company.Common" />
    <inherits name="com.company.Ocean" />
    <inherits name="com.company.Admin" />
    <inherits name="com.company.Air" />
    <inherits name="com.company.Framework" />
    <inherits name="com.company.Finance" />
    <inherits name="com.company.Accurate" />
    <inherits name="com.company.Search" />
```

Below code in pom.xml of **main module**

```
<modules>
    <module>company-core</module>
    <module>company-common</module>
    <module>company-ocean</module>
    <module>company-admin</module>
    <module>company-air</module>
    <module>company-framework</module>
    <module>company-finance</module>
    <module>company-accurate</module>
    <module>company-search</module>
</modules>
```

with current structure if i do changes in particular module then it forces to compile all other modules even if there are no changes in other modules.

**Example** I do changes in **com.company.Search** module so project compile all modules. Therefore it takes near about **30 minutes** compilation time.

**Expected** If I do changes in **com.company.Search** module then only **com.company.Search** module should compile not all modules and **reduce the compile time** as well.

Comment: How do you call Maven? via `mvn clean ...package`?

Comment: Using clean install command

Comment: Ok than it's clear why everything is done completely..By using `clean` you remove everything has been generated before...Apart from that `install` is not really necessary...`package` instead. So simply using `mvn package`?

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try with mvn package

Comment: Do you have any idea about memory management in gwt because i just upgrade my project to gwt-2.8.1 with having 16GB ram and my project takes near about 15GB and it throws out off memory error. Also am not able to run project in super dev mode because  out off memory error. So currently I have to close all other application during project compile

Comment: How have you configured the memory settings for the buildj process ?

Comment: We have configured gwt-maven-plugin as <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx9999m -Djava.io.tmpdir=${basedir}/tmp -Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=DisabledPreferencesFactory -Dgwt.jjs.permutationWorkerFactory=com.google.gwt.dev.ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory</extraJvmArgs>

Comment: That's only for running the unit tests but not for the rest. So it looks like your unit tests have a problem you should investigate your Unit Tests why they need so much memory...